# displaying the successfull msg in same page

Tags: html, jsp

I want to display my success msg in d same page only..how i can display the success msg in that same page..when im trying it is gng to another page..can u pls edit dat cod en help me...

```
            <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
       <%      String saveFile = "";   
         String contentType = request.getContentType();  
            if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf 
          ("multipart/form-data") >= 0))                {        
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());     
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();        
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];       
int byteRead = 0;        
int totalBytesRead = 0;       
while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {       
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);            
totalBytesRead += byteRead;           
}           
String file = new String(dataBytes);        
saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);       
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));           
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,  
       saveFile.indexOf("\""));       
int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");           
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1, contentType.length());          
int pos;           
pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");           
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;         
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;          
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;          
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;     
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;          
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;          
saveFile = "D:/CETAF/Configuration Repository/Configuration/" + saveFile;         
File ff = new File(saveFile);          
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);          
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));           
fileOut.flush();            
fileOut.close();%><Br><table border="2">
           <tr>         
     <td><b>You have successfully upload the file by the name of:</b>         
        <%                  
        out.println(saveFile);                 
        }        
          %>          
         </td>      
          </tr>
         </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save a session variable here saying "success" naming it something specific to this operation, redirect back to previous page, read the session variable there and display your success message then set that session variable back to null.